# Attribute error while reading file from CSV module

Tags: python, csv, module

I am getting error while reading a csv file "example.csv", below is the code for the same :

```
import csv

with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    readCsv=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for row in readCsv:
    print row
```

The error I am getting is :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

Comment: Please use code formatting and align the code.

Comment: Can you post the entire traceback? It's probably because you have a `csv.py` file in your current directory.

Comment: Strange. `csv` should have a `reader` attribute. Please `print(dir(csv))`. Perhaps you are importing from the wrong place.

Comment: This way you will get a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`. Indent the `for` loop and it should be just fine. Tested and worked for me.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem, that was because of that csv.py file @nir0s